# append child using array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I write the xml using c#, and I want to make this script shorter, anyone know how to do it? I was think about using array,but don't know how to create the array...

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode contentElements = doc.CreateElement("content");
doc.AppendChild(contentElements);
xmlNode itemElement1 = doc.CreateElement("item1");
xmlNode itemElement2 = doc.CreateElement("item2");
xmlNode itemElement3 = doc.CreateElement("item3");
xmlNode itemElement4 = doc.CreateElement("item4");
xmlNode itemElement5 = doc.CreateElement("item5");
contentElements.AppendChild(itemElement1);
contentElements.AppendChild(itemElement2);
contentElements.AppendChild(itemElement3);
contentElements.AppendChild(itemElement4);
contentElements.AppendChild(itemElement5);
```

Thanks a lot~~~

Comment: Use  [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `XmlDocument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array as shown below

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode contentElements = doc.CreateElement("content");
doc.AppendChild(contentElements);
string[] elements = new string[] { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" };
foreach (string element in elements)
{
    XmlNode itemElement = doc.CreateElement(element);
    contentElements.AppendChild(itemElement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ~~~ a lot ~~~~